# Components, binding in Angularjs1.5 - Passing data from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, angular-controller, angular1.6

After I get the accounts and people array from my resolve, how do I access people and accounts in the component controller?  I have also tried the define acctTally in the main ctl and and bind it to the component with no luck.

I can bind people and account just find to the component and access it in the component template, but it I want to do work on either array in the component controller is where I'm having the issue.  What key concept am I missing????

> main controller

```
 angular.module('hellosolarsystem')
  .controller('AcctCtrl', function($scope, accounts, people){
    $scope.accounts = accounts;
    $scope.people = people;
  });
```

> Main template

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
<acct-list people="people" accounts="accounts"></acct-list>
```

> Component

```
function aCtrl(){
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.acctTally = [];
         ctrl.uniqueAcct = [];

         //Array of all accounts
      $scope.people.data.forEach(function(person){
           person.account_types.forEach(function(account){
             ctrl.acctTally.push(account.name);
           })
        });
        }

angular.module('hellosolarsystem').component('acctList', {
  bindings: { accounts: '<',
              people: '<'
            },
  controller: aCtrl,


  templateUrl: 'javascripts/app/components/accounts/acctsList/index.html'
})
```

> Component Template

```
<table class = "table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Accounts</th>
            <th>Number of Accounts Assigned Users</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat = "acct in $ctrl.acctTally">
            <td>{{acct.name}}</td>
            <td>{acct.tally}}<</td>
            <td>
              <button class = "btn btn-info" ng-click = "editUser($index)">Edit</button>
              <button class = "btn btn-danger" ng-click = "deleteUser($index)">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding for component doesn't available when you controller function gets instantiated since AngularJS 1.6 release. Check [breaking changes here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes). Bindings will be available when `$onInit` hook gets called unlike Angular 2+. Even you could enforce the older behaviour of prepopulate bindings when controller gets instantiated by doing

```
.config(function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
})
```

But doing above is highly discourage by Angular team.

Per 1.6.0 breaking changes you have to move your code to `$onInit` hook solve your issue.

```
ctrl.$onInit = function() {
 ctrl.people.data.forEach(function(person){
    person.account_types.forEach(function(account){
       ctrl.acctTally.push(account.name);
    })
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I had tried using $onInit but forgot to attach ctrl to it!